# Neural network: "InverseLayer"

Tags: neural-network, lasagne

I play around with neural networks. I understand how convolutional layers, fully connected layers and many other things work. I also know what a gradient is and how such a network is trained.

The framework lasagne contains a layer called [InverseLayer](https://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers/special.html#lasagne.layers.InverseLayer).

> The InverseLayer class performs inverse operations for a single layer of a neural network by applying the partial derivative of the layer to be inverted with respect to its input.

I do not know what this means or when i should use this layer in general. Or what is the idea behind of inverting the partial derivative?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InversLayer is needed when creating the Deconvolution Network. For more details take a look here: http://cvlab.postech.ac.kr/research/deconvnet/

Comment: I thought for this reason the TransposedConv2dLayer is used? https://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers/conv.html#lasagne.layers.TransposedConv2DLayer Description: "Performs the backward pass of a 2D convolution (also called transposed convolution, fractionally-strided convolution or deconvolution in the literature) on its input and optionally adds a bias and applies an elementwise nonlinearity.". Thanks for the link, i will read the paper:)!

Comment: Indeed the Inverse Layer is doing a TransposedConv2dLayer when it goes backward through a Conv2DLayer. Theano developer team chose this name to be used for all types of layers one would like to invert (MaxPool, DeseLayer).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation:)!